# Proguard and Netty 5 on Android

Tags: android, netty, proguard, obfuscation

I've seen a couple questions regarding this issue, but they are for older versions of Netty.
I have tried their answers, switching org.jboss.netty out with io.netty, but the same error occurs.

I'm trying to compile an Android app that uses Netty 5.0.0Alpha2 (build #16) with Proguard enabled.

Without Proguard, the app runs fine.
As soon as I enable Proguard, I get this exception when it tries to use Netty:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: unknown type parameter 'I': class io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler
    at io.netty.util.internal.TypeParameterMatcher.find0(Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.util.internal.TypeParameterMatcher.find(Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

This is my Proguard config:

```
# billing
-keep class com.android.vending.billing.**

# butterknife
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewInjector {
    *;
}
-keepnames class * {
    @butterknife.InjectView *;
}

# admob
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** {
    public *;
}

-keep public class com.google.ads.** {
    public *;
}

# logging
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log

# netty (partial)
-dontwarn io.netty.**
-dontwarn sun.**
```

I have tested it without the -dontwarn options to see if the warnings would point me in the right direction, but it's all missing optional dependencies like slf4j and Tomcat.

I have also tried excluding all the Netty classes like so:

```
-keep class io.netty.** {
    *;
}
```

...but that does not appear to fix it either.

Comment: I had no idea that netty could be used in Android devices, thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have fixed this issue with some carefully* applied Proguard rules after reading through parts of the rather huge Netty sources:

```
-keepattributes Signature,InnerClasses
-keepclasseswithmembers class io.netty.** {
    *;
}
-keepnames class io.netty.** {
    *;
}
```

My original exception was caused by the type variables being removed from the bytecode, which Netty uses via reflection. `Signature` in `-keepattributes` keeps this information.

You get a slightly different exception if you only do `Signature` on `-keepattributes` - adding `InnerClasses` fixes this one by bringing back even more information in the class files.

Later, I got `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: ctl`; that's what -keepnames is for. This way, the field is still called `ctl` like Netty expects.

Finally, some members (like `ctl`, seen earlier) were being removed by Proguard because Netty only uses them via reflection. The final rule, `-keepclasseswithmembers`, makes sure Proguard doesn't remove them.

If you take this approach, I strongly recommend you use only the Netty jars you need, instead of the -all jar. Switching from -all to just the required Netty jars brought my method count *way* down after I had gone past the 65k limit. Reducing your jars requires bit of trial-and-error though as the separation is unclear and there's not really any resources saying what's what.

<sub>* not carefully at all, I just slapped rules into the file and removed them if they did nothing. There's probably a better way to do this that doesn't keep this information in the *entire* program, but instead just Netty.</sub>

Comment: If someone runs into this issue - "<class> is not a @Sharable handler, so can't be added or removed multiple times.", add `*Annotation*` to the -keepattributes list : `-keepattributes Signature, InnerClasses, *Annotation*`

Answer (score 5):

Una's answer keep too many classes, which makes my app 1MB larger than usual. So I use the rules below:

```
# netty
-keepclassmembernames class io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator {
    *;
}

-keepclassmembernames class io.netty.buffer.AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf {
    *;
}

-keep public class io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil {
    *;
}
```

Comment: This works for me. Adding some more explanations: Netty is using reflection on these 3 classes through `ResourceLeakDetector`. We need to keep those class and member names otherwise there will be runtime ClassNotFoundException for these 3 classes. I think this is the better answer because it keeps the minimal code of Netty library.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your proguard rule if you are using R8 full mode:

```
-keepnames class * extends io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter
-keepnames class * extends io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter
```

The key point is to keep the class name of those classes with generic type, because the `io.netty.util.internal.TypeParameterMatcher` will try to get the generic type param from the class. The exception itself indicates that netty cannot find the type param "I" from the class name because R8 full mode strips the class signature. So the `TypeParameterMatcher` throws an exception.